# How do I make my Minecraft Server automatically start on boot

Tags: xubuntu, 21.10, minecraft

I run multiple Minecraft servers on Ubuntu 21.10, I'd like for them to automatically start when I turn on or restart my machine. I've heard online about systemd services, but I don't quite understand them, if anyone can give me a full guide, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for this answer and ended up having to use chat GPT3 to help iron out the systemd errors. There are most likely some improvements that could be made, but this should at least give a baseline working service from what I've found.

This was the final /etc/systemd/system/minecraft-server.service file that would work on Ubuntu Server 22.04

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Bedrock Server

Wants=network.target

[Service]
KillMode=none
SuccessExitStatus=0 1
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/server
ExecStart=/path/to/server/bedrock_server LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server >/dev/null 2>&1 &
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
Killmode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

A few things that I didn't understand about it, but will hopefully help someone who had the same issues

LD_LIBRARY_PATH could not be set beforehand to an absolute path. This would let the server technically start, but would error out not being able to find the server.properties file. "WorkingDirectory" fixes this issue, but not sure why the LD_LIBRARY_PATH could not be just an absolute path variable.

ExecStart=/Path/to/server/bedrock_server - I have no idea why this is needed as I'm reading it as running the executable before setting the path, then re-running the executable, but it won't work without it.